# How to get assigned value when a spec is run in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm using the `FriendlyId` gem and it generates a slug when a record is saved. It works great.

I can route to the slug like: `places/house-of-dead`, perfect. But I'm having a problem when it comes to testing.

I'm using `FactoryGirl` to stub the parameters that I'm going to create, but I don't know how to get that generated slug to assert if my route redirects to it, my test is below and (`???? should be the generated slug`).:

```
    context '#create' do
      it 'should redirect to place after created' do
        place = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:place)

        post :create, { place: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:place) }

        response.should redirect_to places_path(slug: ????)
      end
    end
```

My controller is simple:

```
def create
    @place = Place.new(params[:place])

    # setting up who owns this place
    @place.user = current_user

    if @place.save
      flash[:success] = "Place created."

      redirect_to @place
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

As you can see, I use `redirect_to @place` and it redirects me to `place/:slug', but when it comes to testing that redirect, how do I do it?

Also, is my testing way right/good?

Thanks.

Comment: `should redirect_to place_path(place.to_param)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost answered yourself:

```
response.should redirect_to places_path(assigns(:place))
```

or if you need to use the slug:

```
response.should redirect_to places_path(slug: assigns(:place).slug)
```

See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#assigns for more on `assigns()`.

And this line

```
place = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:place)
```

is redundant, as you never use the `place` variable in the rest of your test.